# Encode PDF to base64 in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, base64

Please help me!
How can I encode file to string base64 in react

```
handleUploadFile(event) {
  let file = event.target.files[0]

  // here encoding file base64?

  this.setState({
    fileData: file,
    fileName: file.name
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can try out :

```
handleUploadFile(event) {
    let selectedFile = event.target.files;
    let file = null;
    let fileName = "";
    //Check File is not Empty
    if (selectedFile.length > 0) {
        // Select the very first file from list
        let fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
        fileName = fileToLoad.name;
        // FileReader function for read the file.
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        // Onload of file read the file content
        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
            file = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
            // Print data in console
            console.log(file);
        };
        // Convert data to base64
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }

  this.setState({
    fileData: file,
    fileName: fileName
  })
}
```

You may need to change it for multiple files though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me.